# Error: command stage_ros not implemente

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed stage_ros in my computer but when I try to run using "rosrun stage_ros stageros $(rospack stage_ros)/world/willow-erratic.world" I get the following:

[rospack] Error: command stage_ros not implemented
[FATAL] [1437511362.267388529]: The world file /world/willow-erratic.world does not exist.
[Loading /world/willow-erratic.world]err: unable to open world file /world/willow-erratic.world : No such file or directory (/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-stage-4.1.1-4trusty-20150424-0404/libstage/worldfile.cc Load)

I'm not sure if it has something to do with how my environmental variables are set up or if I'm missing something.

**EDIT 1**

I got stage_ros to work now, I'm able to run thtat command line with no errors, I forgot to add the 'find' key word. This is the output in the command line:
$ rosrun stage_ros stageros $(rospack find stage_ros)/world/willow-erratic.world
[Loading /opt/ros/indigo/share/stage_ros/world/willow-erratic.world]
warn: worldfile /opt/ros/indigo/share/stage_ros/world/willow-erratic.world:21 : property [laser_return] is defined but not used (/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-stage-4.1.1-4trusty-20150424-0404/libstage/worldfile.cc WarnUnused)
[ INFO] [1437593174.136336700]: Found 1 laser devices and 0 cameras in robot 0

Now I'm having some issues installing the controllers, http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers. I downloaded, extracted and moved the folder to my catkin_ws. I catkin_make it and used the rosmake command but when I run the rosrun command in the tutorial I get the following error:

$ rosrun stage stageros 'rospack find stage_controllers'/world/roomba-wander.world
[rospack] Error: package 'stage' not found
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named stageros below

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214328/error:-command-stage_ros-not-implemente/) by [negotiator14](https://answers.ros.org/users/23016/negotiator14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) on 2015-07-23**:
It should be `rosrun stage_ros stageros 'rospack find stage_controllers'/world/roomba-wander.world`. The "stage" package became a system dependency and the "stageros" node went into the "stage_ros" wrapper package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed `stage_ros`? And I think you messed up your command a little... This worked on mine: `rosrun stage_ros stageros $(rospack find stage_ros)/world/willow-erratic.world`

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0